# SQL how many items of certain level are correct (query issue)?

Tags: android, sql

To make a big sql structure simple: I am having next structure:

```
id    level    answercorrect    points
1     1        0                0
2     1        1                60
3     1        1                80
4     1        1                77
5     1        1                92
6     1        0                0
7     2        0                0
8     2        0                0
9     2        0                0
10    2        1                80
11    2        0                0
12    2        0                0
```

I now want to display two things:

**1)** how many levels were completed (this is min. half of the questions correct)

**2)** the level where you scored the most points.

Now I can go and manually do a query for each level, then compare them and then output them.

```
SELECT (*) FROM QUESTIONS WHERE LEVEL = level AND ANSWERCORRECT = 1
```

But Is there a way to do this quicker? It just seems like a to big bunch of code to accomplish that on my way..?

Comment: 1/ don't understand. define 'completed'. 2/ select max(points), level from questions ?

Comment: 1/ if there are in this example 6 elements in level 1, there have to be minimum 3 items with ansercorrect = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show you each level, with a count of answers, and a count of correct answers.

```
select level, 
    count(*) as totalquestions, 
    sum (answercorrect) as correctanswers,
    sum (points) as totalpoints
from yourtable
group by level
having sum (answercorrect) >= (count(*)/2)
order by sum (points) desc
```

Or

```
select level,  
    count(*) as totalquestions,  
    sum (answercorrect) as correctanswers, 
    sum (points) as totalpoints,
    case when sum (answercorrect) >= (count(*)/2) then 1 else 0 end as completed
from yourtable 
group by level 
order by sum (points) desc
```

It seems superfluous to store points and correctness, if points = 0 implies incorrect and points>0 implies correct?

Comment: This will restrict levels returned to those which have been completed - conceivably, more points might have been scored on a level which has not been completed. I suggest removing the `having` clause, and adding a conditional field to show whether the level has been completed.

Comment: thanks, how you mean adding a conditional field? You mean like a second query?

Comment: If you remove the `having` clause and add `case when sum (answercorrect) >= (count(*)/2) then 1 else 0 end as completed` to the select then you can have a field that indicates completion.

Comment: Thanks guys! I should get it rolling with this info :) It sounds clear too.

Comment: Mmm.. I am getting this error: 10-10 08:57:48.004: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.droid.app/com.droid.app.Score}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "case": syntax error: , while compiling: select level,count(*) as totalquestions,sum (answercorrect) as correctanswers,sum (points) as totalpoints from questions group by level case when sum (answercorrect) >= (count(*)/2) then 1 else 0 end as completed order by sum (points) desc

Comment: @JackCommonw: As mentioned in both podiluska and my first comments, you should **remove the having clause** - the `case` should appear after `totalpoints` and before `from yourtable`.

Comment: You should add the `case..` to the select, not the `group by`, with a `,` before it - see edit.

Comment: Yeah I did remove the having clause, i just placed the case at the wrong place I guess.. let me try

Comment: I noticed one error.. in the line sum(points) as totalpoints it will count all the points while it only has to count the points of the questions where the answercorrect = 1. The thing is, you can try giving an answer but you will get minus points if it is wrong, and this current score is stored there as well... so i tried "sum (points) as totalpoints where answercorrect = 1, but then it crashes because i assume the where statement is there too early and cannot be modified to a certain piece of my query? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @JackCommonw `sum(case answercorrect when 1 then points else 0 end)`

Comment: Damn awesome! May I ask if you know any good tuts on sql queries to recommend? Obviously I found some on google, but there might be some better then the rest? :) It's just new to me but I think it is an interesting matter which I want to get to know better?

Comment: Ps, to count the total levels which are completed, best way to do it ? : do I have to go through some kind of while loop and count the c.getInt(4)?

Comment: @podiluska, is it also possible to get the number of completed levels out of this query? Or do I have to loop through the results somehow? Thanks!

Comment: @JackCommonw You could add `(select count(*) from ( select level from @t group by level having sum (answercorrect) >= (count(*)/2) ) t  ) completedlevels` to the selects which will give you another field, but if you're looping through the data, you may as well count

Comment: @podiluska   
I now have Cursor c = myDataBase .rawQuery( "select level, " + "count() as totalquestions, " + "sum (answercorrect) as correctanswers, " + "sum(case answercorrect when 1 then score else 0 end), " + "(count() from ( select level from questions group by level having sum (answercorrect) >= (count()/2) ) questions ) completedlevels, " + "case when sum (answercorrect) >= (count()/2) then 1 else 0 end as completed " + "from questions " + "group by level " + "order by sum (score) desc ",null);but i get error if i run it..you see the fault?

Comment: @JackCommonw CompletedLevels should start `(SELECT count() from...`

Comment: @podiluska it totally works, awesome! Hey may I ask, you know any good tuts on sql queries to recommend? Like I said before, I do find them on internet, but there might be some very good ones you know of? :)